# Will auto-updates still apply to extant app installs if I remove my app from the app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an iOS app that I am deprecating. I've prepared a new version of the app that, on launch, will say "Sorry, but this app is being removed, please use our website instead" and provides a link to our site.

What I'd like to do is

1. Release this update
2. As soon as it is approved, remove the app from the iTunes App Store

The intent is that customers with the app already installed will get auto-upgrade to the new version with the deprecation message, and no new installs will be ever happen.

However it's not clear to me if updates will get pushed out if I remove the app from the store. Does anyone have experience with this? Any reason this plan will not work?

Comment: You may have a bigger issue - Apple may not approve the update since the update makes the app useless.

Comment: We're going to make API changes that will break the mobile app, but aren't going to update the app in sync; so what's the answer? Apple would prefer I knowingly break the app to deprecating it gracefully?

Comment: Provide API v2. All new development uses the new API. Your old app keeps using the old API. Update your old app to use the new API.

Comment: I'm not going to maintain a backwards compatible API for use with an app that we no longer support that a fraction of folks use. Given infinite resources, sure, but practically speaking; what is the 'right' deprecation path for a company that is no longer providing a mobile app?